# where the file is located in netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans IDE as for PHP developemnt. At this moment I'm looking on a open source project, and I'll like to understand it. The thing is that I don't know where a certain file is located. There is a feature in eclipse wich allows you to see exactly where is placed a file in the project root in real time, even while you switch tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover the mouse over the tab name, the location of the file will be shown as pop-up message